# How do you categorize a pending transaction immediately after making a purchase and have it save?

Tags: transactions, currency, linux-mint, categorization

I’d like to be able to instantly confirm or modify a transactions’s category and any associated tags immediately upon purchasing something with a credit/debit card. For example, I’d like if I could immediately categorize a transaction by a press and long-hold gesture on my iPhone when the Apple Pay notification badge pings my phone right after I purchase something. The issue I run into with Mint, or apps like it is that 1) I have to log into an app to categorize it and 2) when I categorize a pending transaction, I have to re-categorize it once it processes. This creates problems because then I have to remember that transaction days later.

I already said everything needed above.